# How to serialize GQLAlchemy model objects to JSON?

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to serialize objects from Python objects to JSON properties. I'm using GQLAlchemy and Memgraph. So the question is, how can I serialize GQLAlchemy model objects to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the model objects are [pydantic objects](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/), it should be quite easy by just calling `object.dict()`.